# how to make second post tags meta box in WordPress editor?

Tags: wordpress, meta, box

I'm programming a movieDB template on WordPress and I need to add Actors names and Directors as Tag.

But I need to make separate Tag meta boxes in WordPress Editor.
One for actors and one for directors and one for genres.
I'm using default post type of WordPress which is posts.

How can I add more meta boxes like post tag meta box?

Let me know if you have any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

these days I use Advanced Custom Fields (Theme mode) to generate meta boxes in any format.

Answer (score 1):

You can create new taxonomy using [wp_register_taxonomy()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/) and set `meta_box_cb` param as `'post_tags_meta_box'`.

Comment: Thank you but I did not get.
can you whrite the code here?
I really will be happy :)